# SwiftUI DatePicker flipped numbers in RTL

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to use a DatePicker in an RTL app (changed the project development region to he).
However, I see unexpected behavior, the date numbers are flipped **(video included)**.
I already opened a feedback at Apple and even contacted them but no reply so far (3 months).

I noticed that Apple's built in apps like calendar do present the date numbers correctly.
Any help what can cause that? 
Thanks.

My app: [click here](https://streamable.com/wn9q5l)
Apple's calendar app: [click here](https://streamable.com/sey6mh)

Here is my code

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            Form {
                DatePicker(selection: $printDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Label("Choose Date", systemImage: "calendar").font(.headline)
                }
.......
    }
}
```

Edit (23 Dec 2022): it has probably been a but since it works now!

Comment: DatePicker has so many bugs in SwiftUI. Looks like Appe Calendar is written in UIKit.  Have you tried using a UIKit view for this part of ur app?

Comment: I have no idea how to use UIKit. Also, I am afraid of it being buggy and I want my app to be 100% SwiftUI. If using UIKit is the last option I will do so. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Watch a video on implementing UIKit code in SwiftUI. It is not too hard and works pretty reliably. Best of luck

Comment: After trying with UIKit, I still see this bug... I set the locale of the UIDatePicker to "he" and still the same.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem in Arabic. I tried setting the semantic content attribute on the date picker to forceRightToLeft but still the issue exist. I'm yet to test on a real device to see if it's a simulator issue. One way to fix the numbers is to just swipe on any direction and it will fix the numbers, but the scrolling still doesn't respect right to left (tapping the arrows on the top scrolls to the opposite direction).

Comment: Also debugging the view hierarchy in Xcode shows the correct layout. I think there's a bug somewhere in the new picker that's causing the flipping to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it (swift solution), the compact date picker consists of the following:

1- Time: UIPicker

2- Date: Collection View

So first you need to get the orientation of your device and set it the semanticContentAttribute of UIPicker & CollectionView

```
UICollectionView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDatePicker.self]).updateSemantics(Localization.getLayoutDirection())
UIPickerView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDatePicker.self]).updateSemantics(Localization.getDeviceDirection())
```

The main issue is related to the locale, this will work correctly if you set the locale from the storyboard or implement the date picker programmatically.